# Hazelcast IMap.putAll without call mapstore.store() or storeall

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have 2 nodes hazelcast server. I need import 10M rows data into imap (with mapstore). i have not call  putTransient because it is slow(max 6K puts/s).Can i call imap.putAll() without call mapstore for increase performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your `MapStore` as write-behind, the `MapStore` operations doesn't block your `IMap` calls including `putAll`. Please see the details for configuration here: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.5/manual/html-single/index.html#setting-write-behind-persistence